# what does this function represent ? is this a special function?

Tags: functions

I don't understand what this function means ? is it a well known function or does this refer to a concept in physics?

$$
f(x) = \frac{\lambda^x}{x!} e^{-\lambda}
$$

Comment: Where does this function appear?

Comment: Looks like the PMF of the Poisson Distribution (if $x$ is supposed to be a natural number, which makes sense due to the factorial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Poisson Distribution's Probability Mass Function.
It describes the probability of a random variable $X$ to be equal to $x$.

For example, it can be used to describe the probability that a certain amount of cars $x$ will pass through somewhere in the road in a certain timeframe.
More generally, it is useful when looking at events that happen independently but in a constant average rate.
The constant $\lambda$ represents the "rate" of occurence.